# Can I run AVD on a Virtual Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, virtualization, virtual-desktop, windows-virtual-desktop

I am currently working form home for an organisation.
Is it possible to run Android Emulator via Android Studio on a Virtual Desktop which has Windows 10 installed. 
Also, should I keep my specs low for the Emulator, as I have enough RAM in my VDI.
And do I need to ask the organisation to enable Virtualization in the Virtual Machine, As it may not be possible for me to do so. Or, there is no such things in Virtual Machines?

Currently, When I try to run Emulator, it just gets stuck on black screen forever and timeouts.
I have tried multiple options. But none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

No, after digging in a lot.
It was Azure VDI, windows 10.

And it's not possible to run a virtual machine (Android Emulator) inside another virtual machine.
It may be possible to run in another OS.
But not on Windows which asks to enable Hyper-V.
Which won't allow installation of Intel HAXM.